# Android game speed on screen size

Tags: android, size, screen

I have had a recurring problem which has continued to surface the past couple of years and I'd like to finally resolve it.

So I have an Android game which is a bit like Space Invaders (enemies in a line move across the screen). The issue I have is with supporting different screen sizes with Surface View. Clearly the distance the enemy moves will be dependent on the screen size to keep the same difficulty level. So I have a ratio for width and height that I multiply everything by to make sure everything is drawn in the correct locations proportional to the screen size. Such as the following:

```
posX += (int)(GameScreen.wRatio * speed + 0.5f);
```

The obvious problem here is that posX is an int and I am casting a float (since drawing a bitmap only takes int parameters). So what ends up happening, is that in some cases the position will be rounded up to the next int making the game faster than it should be. Or, in some cases posX is rounded to 0.

What would be the best approach to avoid this? I can assume that always incrementing by the smallest I can ( by 1 ) and then skipping increments for particular enemies on each update of the game loop. But, this would require a lot of changes to my code and I would like to hear what other suggestions there may be before I do that.

Comment: why do you have the 0.5f added to the speed? this isn't going to change relative to screen size.....

Comment: It was a long time since I wrote this code but I believe I was following a tutorial at the time. It was something that recommended to do before casting to an int.

Comment: That sounds a bit odd. This could be what is causing the game to 'Speed up' at times. It would probably be more noticeable on smaller screens. Have you tried running it without `0.5f` to see if its any better?

Comment: Come to think of it I think that it is a kind of guard to stop posX being 0. If the ratio * speed ends up below 0.5 it'd be rounded to 0, so that ensures it goes to at least 1. I can give it a shot however

Comment: Did it make any difference?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Still getting different speeds on different phones